# Poisson variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

The number of daily flaws of the machines of a factory is given by a Poisson variable with mean 3.
Each flaw is fixed by one maintenance employee in a whole day.
How many maintenance employees are needed if they want to fix every flaw with probability 0.9?

So far I've thought that if $X$ is the number of daily flaws then $X \sim Poisson(3)$

And so $X$ is also the number of employees needed.

So we would be looking for an n (number of employees) such that $\mathbb{P}(\mbox{ fixing every flaw }) =0.9$

Then, fixing every flaw only happens if X=n.

So we would be looking for a n such that $\mathbb{P}(X=n) =0.9$ i.e.
$\frac{e^{-3}3^n}{n!}=0.9$

But that does not make sense, Or does it?

Comment: No, there's a certain probability $p_0$ that there are no flaws, $p_1$ that there is one flaw, $p_2$ that there are two flaws, etc.  If you have only two workers, you have only probability $p_0+p_1+p_2$ of fixing every flaw in one day.  Is that at least equal to $0.9$?  If not, then two ain't enough.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: @BrianTung yes, thank you!